# keep only Microsoft drivers

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

i want to delete all drivers from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore` then restore only built-in Microsoft drivers from installation CD.
what are my chances ?

Comment: If you do this I guarantee you will make your system not bootable.  What you want is indeed possible it just won't do what you actually want to do, which isn't clear, because removing all drivers except Microsoft drivers makes no sense.

Comment: You do realize that doing Windows Update (and allowing Windows to get drivers from Windows Update) can actually provide non-Microsoft drivers? So yeah as Ramhound said, doing this could easily make your system not bootable. Is there any particular reason why you need this happening?

Comment: well I guess i messed once with RAS and the WAN miniports, this is all about an error I get **error 633** i made a previous question about it but no one answer it and I also have an other question ... for what mean people dislikes questions??? to dislike an answer yes but what helps in dislikeing questions ??

Comment: Your question is not clear, which is the reason, I issued a down vote.  I neither like your question or dislike it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use the device manager / command line PnP utility (pnputil) to remove unnecessary 3rd party driver packages. As others said in the comments, straight-up deleting drivers from those folders is both a bad idea and pointless. Not only would you blow away system critical device driver files, but you wouldn't remove the references to those files either (not that it would really matter at that point, since I seriously doubt you could boot after that).

Moreover, it might not be a good idea to delete 3rd party packages unless you're sure you don't need them. Ask yourself, why am I doing this? Are you having problems with your system that would be fixed simply by updating the drivers?

Anyway, here's the output/usage of "pnputil /?":

```
Microsoft PnP Utility
Usage:
------
pnputil.exe [-f | -i] [ -? | -a | -d | -e ] <INF name>
Examples:
pnputil.exe -a a:\usbcam\USBCAM.INF      -> Add package specified by USBCAM.INF
pnputil.exe -a c:\drivers\*.inf          -> Add all packages in c:\drivers\
pnputil.exe -i -a a:\usbcam\USBCAM.INF   -> Add and install driver package
pnputil.exe -e                           -> Enumerate all 3rd party packages
pnputil.exe -d oem0.inf                  -> Delete package oem0.inf
pnputil.exe -f -d oem0.inf               -> Force delete package oem0.inf
pnputil.exe -?                           -> This usage screen
```

pnputil -e would allow you to see the 3rd party packages, pnputil -d oem#.inf would delete a 3rd party package.

Comment: no no its far away from updating them I doubt that I manually changed some drivers , or deleted some ....I'm just wondering if drivers are able to be restored after deleting them , by the way I'm an advanced user, so I'm trying to recognize issues by causing them... that's how i learnt basically I appreciate your help thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but Windows should revert back to no driver / a generic driver if you uninstall a 3rd party driver, assuming there were no previously installed versions of it...

Comment: An advance user would ask if they should delete these files they would know the answer to, "will they come back", they won't,...

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't challenging or barging by saying ***"I'm an advanced user"***  I know they won't come back, that's why I used the word "restored" ... to see if there is a possibility by just restoring built-in drivers from windows CD will fix the system after failing the boot when someones deletes them